# How can i add single quote inside eval function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

Hello i have binded this link button inside my repeater like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddtocart" Text="Add To Cart" 
CssClass="buttonlight" 
ToolTip="Add To Cart" runat="server" 
OnClientClick='<%# "return InsertProduct("+Email.Encryptdes(Eval("product_id").ToString()) +",1)" %>'
></asp:LinkButton>
```

and 
Javascript function

```
function InsertProduct(product_id,qty)
{

    }
```

Output of Email.Encryptdes(Eval("product_id").ToString()) +",1) is this

> return InsertProduct(Fc81hnZ20cpotk1HoHRPUg==.html,1);

So when i click on button it shows error in console incorrect syntax near ***.(dot)*** 
So i want it to be

> return InsertProduct('Fc81hnZ20cpotk1HoHRPUg==.html',1);

How can i achieve this i have tried a lot but strangly it single quote does not shows in browser

```
[Updated]
```

now my browser pure html shows like this

```
<a onclick="return InsertProduct(&quot;&lt;%# Email.Encryptdes(Eval(&quot;product_id&quot;).ToString()) %&gt;&quot; ,1);" id="ctl00_contentplaceHolder2_control2_rptrnew_products_ctl00_btnAddtocart" title="Add To Cart" class="buttonlight" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentplaceHolder2$control2$rptrnew_products$ctl00$btnAddtocart','')">Add To Cart</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it on code behind would make it quite simple

```
btnAddtocart.OnClientClick = "return InsertProduct('"+Email.Encryptdes(Eval("product_id").ToString()) +"',1)"
```

There is one more solution you can try, you can take the call to some other javacript function.

*HTML*

```
OnClientClick='return callToFunction()'
```

*Javascript*

```
function callToFunction()
{
   return InsertProduct("<%= Email.Encryptdes(Eval("product_id").ToString()) %>",1)
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for reply it works but can i do on source file? i don't want it on code behind

Comment: <%= Email.Encryptdes is a serverside function i can no call it from javascript

Comment: The way you were trying in the asp:LinkButton tag. Is this asp:LinkButton  in some databound control like gridview, if so then you can do in RowDataBound event

Comment: Yes i just want your confirmation that 
`OnClientClick='<%# "return InsertProduct('"+Email.Encryptdes(Eval("product_id").ToString()) +"',1)" %>'`
This is not working is this possible or should i go for databound method? Yes i am using repeater control

Comment: I think you can do that, tell me who this one goes> OnClientClick='return InsertProduct(<%# Email.Encryptdes(Eval("product_id").ToString()) %> ,1);'

Comment: Means? don't understood

Comment: I have changed the way you used in line scriptlet, try this if it works?

Comment: But it's same as i have used i want single quote in insertproduct (`'here out put comes from static method'`,1) so javascript function can be called is this possible ?

Comment: I think it is possible, try this, OnClientClick='return InsertProduct("<%# Email.Encryptdes(Eval("product_id").ToString()) %>" ,1);'

Comment: Try using \ as escape character for double quote

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42919/discussion-between-dholakiyaankit-and-adil)